# Добавление чисел в двумерный массив

Tags: python, массивы

Задача звучит так:

> В диапазоне натуральных чисел от 2 до 99 определить, сколько из них
>   кратны каждому из чисел в диапазоне от 2 до 9

Я захотел посмотреть какие числа кратны каждому из чисел от 2 до 9. Предполагал, что на выход получу количество чисел и массив с этими числами.

```
def task1():
arr_result = [0]*10
arr_spam = [[None]]*10
for i in range (2, 100):
    for j in range(2,10):
        if i % j == 0:
            arr_result[j] += 1
            arr_spam[j].append(i)  
for line in range (2,10):
    print(f'{arr_result[line]} чисел кратно {line}')
    print(arr_spam[line])
```

Проблема в том, что в `arr_spam[]` все элементы одинаковы и содержат все числа:

```
[None, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 18, 18, 18, 18, 20, 20, 20, 
21, 21, 22, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 26, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 30, 30, 30, 30, 32, 32, 32, 33, 34, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 38, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 42, 42, 42, 42, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45, 46, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 50, 50, 51, 52, 52, 54, 54, 54, 54, 55, 56, 56, 56, 56, 57, 58, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 62, 63, 63, 63, 64, 64, 64, 65, 66, 66, 66, 68, 68, 69, 70, 70, 70, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 74, 75, 75, 76, 76, 77, 78, 78, 78, 80, 80, 80, 80, 81, 81, 82, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 88, 88, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 
91, 92, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 98, 98, 99, 99]
```

Как решить эту проблему? 
Буду благодарен за ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте список списков с помощью генератора

```
arr_spam = [[] for _ in range(10)]
```

А в вашем случае 10 копий ссылаются на один и тот же объект